# PHP error_log not working

Tags: php, apache2, log-files

I'm using slim framework and I've added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the first line of my public/index.php file.

I'm using apache2 and Ubuntu 18.

This is conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /pathtoproject/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    php_flag log_errors on
        php_flag display_errors on
    php_flag display_startup_errors on
        php_value error_log ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/php_errors.log
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    <Directory "/pathtoproject/public">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
                <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                        RewriteEngine on
                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
                </IfModule>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And this is how my phpinfo looks like

[image]

My error log file permissions

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data     0 Dec  6 20:36 php_errors.log
```

Comment: Try without setting `php_flag` in the settings and using `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` in your php file. Are errors being displayed on screen?